# Active Shell Item not set in Xamarin Shell

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.shell

I'm trying to use the newly introduced Shell object in Xamarin to do the navigation and the child pages but I'm stumbling up with some issues setting up the shell.

This is my markup:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Shell xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
       xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:App.Views.FLMobile"
       FlyoutBehavior="Flyout"
       x:Class="App.Views.FLMobile.AppShell">

    <FlyoutItem Title="MyTabApp" Shell.TabBarIsVisible="False" FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsMultipleItems">
        <ShellContent Title="Bears" IsTabStop="true" Icon="" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate pages:MainPage}" />
    </FlyoutItem>

    <ShellContent Title="About" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate pages:MenuPage}" />
</Shell>
```

And the code behind:

```
namespace App.Views.FLMobile
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class AppShell : Xamarin.Forms.Shell
    {
        public AppShell()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

This is the error I'm getting:

> System.ArgumentException: 'Active Shell Item not set. Have you added
>   any Shell Items to your Shell? Parameter name: ShellItem'

Comment: I make a sample with your code. It works well. You could download ShellDemo2 from GitHub:https://github.com/WendyZang/Test. If you still have the problem, you could upload a sample on Github for me to download and test.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the latest version of Xamarin Forms?

If not I would suggest you upgrade to it as it has many bug fixes.

Secondly, the issue is that you are directly using the shell content without a flyout item
so what you actually need to do is something like:

```
<FlyoutItem Title="MyTabApp" Shell.TabBarIsVisible="False" FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsMultipleItems">        
<ShellContent Title="About" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate pages:MenuPage}" />
</FlyoutItem>
```